# Convert all variables to factors keeping level NA

Tags: r, apply, factors

I've reviewed plenty of topics on the matter but I am missing something - I assume something general in R.

Basically I want to convert all variables in a data frame into factors while also making NA additional level.

```
#Creating Data Frame
data<-data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3,3,3,4,NA),var2=c("a","b","c","d",NA,"a","b"))
```

If I run `factor` function only on one variable using the **exclude** option it works:

```
levels(factor(data$var1,exclude=NULL))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" NA
```

If I use `apply` it seems that this information is lost. It could be due to **matrix-data.frame** coercion

I tried both:

```
data.factors<-data.frame(apply(data, 2,x,exclude=NULL))
data.factors<-data.frame(apply(data, 2, function(x) factor(x,exclude=NULL)))
```

and the results is without NAs as a separate level:

```
levels(x.factors$var1)
[1] " 1" " 2" " 3" " 4"
```

I can then add on a separate step new level for the NAs but this would increase the volume of scripting and I was hoping it can be done in one step?
Any suggestions?

(I apologize if the answer is readily available - I went through a lot of topics and did not find it)

Comment: Try `data[] <- lapply(data, factor, exclude = NULL)` maybe

Comment: You should rarely (if ever) use `apply` on a `data.frame`. If you want to perform functions column-wise, use `lapply`, as @DavidArenburg showed.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You should post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are operating on a `matrix`/`array` or doing rowwise operations, avoid `apply` at all cost due to its conversion to a matrix feature.

`lapply` avoids the conversion part and is much more efficient. You can also update your original data set using `[]` which keeps the original structure of your data set and avoids converting it back to a list as in

```
data[] <- lapply(data, factor, exclude = NULL)
```

Then, you can validate

```
lapply(data, levels)
# $var1
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" NA 
# 
# $var2
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" NA
```

---

As a bonus, you could also try `data.table::set` function which is my prefered work horse for such operations

```
library(data.table)
for(j in names(data)) set(data, j = j, value = factor(data[[j]], exclude = NULL))
```

The code is harder to understand but this should be very efficient when you'll deal with huge data sets.

Comment: This IS the answer! Much appreciated! Also thanks for the comment on apply - I've been using the more than lapply - obviously not the best choice!